# Spring Batch EmptyResultDataAccessException while deleting

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a batch job that reads data from multiple tables on a datasource with a complicated select query with many joins and writes to a table on a different datasource using an insert query.

```
@Bean
public JdbcCursorItemReader<Employee> myReader2() {
    JdbcCursorItemReader<Employee> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
    reader.setSql(COMPLICATED_QUERY_WITH_MANY_JOINS);
    reader.setDataSource(dataSourceOne);
    reader.setPreparedStatementSetter(new MyPrepStSetterOne());
    reader.setRowMapper(new EmployeeRowMapper());
    return reader;
}

Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Employee> myWriter2(DataSource dataSource) {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Employee> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
    writer.setSql(INSERT_QUERY);
    writer.setPreparedStatementSetter(new MyPrepStSetterTwo());
    writer.setDataSource(dataSourceTwo);
    return writer;
}
```

I have the above reader and writer in a step.
I want to delete the employee records that were inserted from previous day's job (not all of them) if it could be duplicated by today's records.

So I added another step before the above step with same select query in the reader, but a delete query in the writer.

```
@Bean
public JdbcCursorItemReader<Employee> myReader1() {
    JdbcCursorItemReader<Employee> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
    reader.setSql(COMPLICATED_QUERY_WITH_MANY_JOINS);
    reader.setDataSource(dataSourceOne);
    reader.setPreparedStatementSetter(new MyPrepStSetterOne());
    reader.setRowMapper(new EmployeeRowMapper());
    return reader;
}

Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Employee> myWriter1(DataSource dataSource) {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Employee> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
    writer.setSql(DELETE_QUERY_WHERE_EMPLOYEE_NAME_IS);
    writer.setPreparedStatementSetter(new MyPrepStSetterZero());
    writer.setDataSource(dataSourceTwo);
    return writer;
}
```

I am getting **EmptyResultDataAccessException: Item 3 of 10 did not update any rows**
Because not all of today's records may have been inserted yesterday.

How can I make myWriter1 to ignore if a record does not exist already and proceed to next?

Comment: The logic of `I want to delete the employee records that were inserted from previous day's job (not all of them) if it could be duplicated by today's records.` and `I am getting EmptyResultDataAccessException: Item 3 of 10 did not update any rows Because not all of today's records may have been inserted yesterday.` is not clear (at least to me). Can you please explain the steps of your algorithm without referring to Spring Batch? There is probably another way to implement your requirement without encountering this issue. I'd love to help if the requirement is clear enough in layman terms.

Comment: The batch runs everyday at a certain time.
An employee added in the source yesterday would have been picked up and inserted in the destination by the job.
Same employee can be modified in the source today, and it will be picked up and inserted again in the destination by the job.
I am trying to delete the record that was inserted yesterday, before inserting today.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will add an answer with a possible solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach seems correct. You can set [JdbcBatchItemWriter#setAssertUpdates](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcBatchItemWriter.html#setAssertUpdates-boolean-) to `false` in your writer and this should ignore the case where no records have been updated by your query (which is a valid business case according to your description).